# Complex number z: |z| = 1 => z* = 1/z proof

Tags: complex-numbers

I can t understand how we move from $ |z| =1 \rightarrow z* = \frac{1}{z}, \quad z \in C $  ($z*$ is the complex conjugate)

Comment: If $|z|=1$ then $\exists \varphi \in [0, 2\pi)$ so that $z=e^{i \varphi}$, and $z^*=(e^{i \varphi})^*=e^{-i \varphi}=1/e^{i\varphi}=1/z$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**    square both sides of $|z|=1$ and use $|z|^2={z\bar z}$

Answer (score 2):

$$|z|=1\iff|z|^2=1\iff z\bar{z}=1\iff\bar{z}=\frac1z$$